# Rails: Jumping across two belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have three models...

```
Product
 belongs_to :ProductCategory
 belongs_to :Manufacturer

ProductCategory
 has_many :products

Manufacturer
 has_many :products
```

I'd like to ask an instance of ProductCategory for the set of Manufacturers for Products in that ProductCategory with a call like product_category.manufacturers.

I've currently implemented it in the Products model like this:

```
def manufacturers
  Manufacturer.find(self.products.pluck(:manufacturer_id).uniq.to_a
end
```

Is there a better "rails way"?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is missing a `)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is an extremely well-solved problem and a fundamentally basic part of using Associations in Rails. You want [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association):

```
class ProductCategory
  has_many :products
  has_many :manufacturers, :through => :products
end
```

Comment: I assume I just do product_category.manufacturers.uniq if I want just one record for each manufacturer?  If I do it without uniq, I get one record for each Product...

Comment: Yes, you want `.uniq`. Otherwise, yes, you'll get the manufacturer for each product in the category.